# What is pulsed neutron diffraction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering, experimental-technique, neutrons

I have tried a google search and checked my condensed matter books but I can't find out what pulsed neutron diffraction is and how it differs from inelastic neutron scattering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most fundamental thing is that [*"diffraction"* generally denotes an *elastic* process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_diffraction) in this context. The *"pulsed"* part likely refers to the structure of the beam--a bunch of neutrons in short time, and then a long delay before the next bunch which allows better discrimination of what detected event is related to what beam bucket--always a problem with neutrons which have complicated behaviors on long time scales compared to charged particles.